# Randomized Rounding for Set Cover

Tags: optimization, computer-science, linear-programming, approximation

I am familiar with a randomized rounding-based algrothim for the minmum set cover problem that gives a solution that is $O(log(n))$ close to the optimum. For example, see [here](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/fileadmin/inf/d1/teaching/summer16/random/randomizedrounding.pdf). Is it known whether there are other randomized rounding-based algrothims that give a constant approximation factor instead of the $log(n)$?

Comment: It's impossible to get a better approximation factor using any polynomial time algorithm unless some complexity-theoretic conjecture is true (the result is originally due to Lund & Yannakakis), so I wouldn't expect such an algorithm to exist.

Comment: @VHarisop It would be helpful if you can point out a lower-bound, or a result formalising the notion you've mentioned.

Comment: The exact lower bound is $c \log n$ for some constant $c$. Any approximation factor lower than that is impossible in polynomial time, unless $\mathsf{NP} \subset \mathsf{DTIME}(n^{\mathrm{polylog} n})$. The paper by Lund & Yannakakis has the details.